# Can flip view be used to show large number of itemSource?

Tags: c#, xaml, flipview

I am developing a windows 10 Universal Application.I have a requirement like I need to show the details of a Room when I click on an item in the Rooms List.
I am planning to use a Flip-view control to show the details of a single room.
And When I swipe ,it should show the details of the second item and so on.

My question is if the item source is very large,will it make the app slow or will that create any memory usage issue?

Here is my code

```
      <FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding RoomsCollection}" Loaded="FlipView_Loaded" >
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Room.Id"} HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red"/>
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
```

So if the RoomsCollection goes say more that 1000 since i am using a flip view will the entire collection be loaded initially or is there any kind of visualization implemented by the control?